# where is the correct location to put onclick inside menu bar

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I need to make the logout button goes to login page when I click it

okay so first, I have an action bar at the top of the screen  (it has a different xml file in the menu folder), this action bar contains the logout button.
For the layout of the entire screen(not the menu at the top)There's an xml file in the layout folder called fragment_create_incident which has the layout for the whole screen

I dunno where to add my logout code in create_incident.java to make this work, I've tried placing it inside oncreate but my app shuts down when I run it!

thats the relevant code for the menu bar at the top of the page

create_incident.java

```
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    tools:context="com.example.studentproject.caservicedesk.CreateRequest" >



        <item

        android:id="@+id/logout"

        android:orderInCategory="2"

        android:title="@string/logout"

        android:showAsAction="never"/>


</menu>
```

thats my logout button re-direction code that I want to add in the java code

```
Button logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);

 logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 public void onClick(View v) {

 // Switching to login screen

 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);

 startActivity(i);

 }

 });
```

Thats the activity that I want to add my logout button to it

```
public class CreateIncident extends Activity 
{
private final String TAG = "create_incident";

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{

// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.create_incident, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{

switch (item.getItemId())
{
case R.id.action_bar:
Log.i(TAG, "Action bar item clicked");
return true;
case R.id.home:
Log.i(TAG, "Home item clicked");
return true;
case R.id.logout:
Log.i(TAG, "Logout item clicked");
return true;

default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_create_incident);



}



}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in onOptionsItemSelected handler:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.action_bar:
            Log.i(TAG, "Action bar item clicked");
            return true;
        case R.id.home:
            Log.i(TAG, "Home item clicked");
            return true;
        case R.id.logout: {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logout item clicked");

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
            startActivity(i);

            return true;
        }

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, If i want to clear my sharedpreference data, can I just simply add it there? because I want all the user data that I've saved in login in sharedpreferenced to be erased when the user clicks logout

Comment: Sure, use this:
getSharedPreferences("YourPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().commit();